# Avoid effect to load list

Tags: javascript, php, css, woocommerce

I have a website that load product in a list.

I show a image and description in a list, but while load the list, all the lines is like a one.  I put the image below:

[image]

When the list is loaded I saw like this:

[image]

How to avoid this effect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your list elements the specific height of the wine images like so: `li{height: 100px;}`

It seems they get their height from the images which take a longer time loading.

For more specific answers you should post some code.